# sed replace content within double quotes

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to replace the versionName in a xml file from a shell script using sed.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.sed"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="UNKNOWN VERSION NAME">
```

I've gotten so far as to search for a line containing versionName but **how to tell sed to replace everything within the double quotes coming directly after versionName?**

```
sed -i .old '/versionName/ s/WHAT TO WRITE?/NEW VERSION NAME/' AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: `"\([^"]*\)` should work

Comment: it would be better to use `xmlstarlet`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `not-"`, like this:

```
sed -i .old '/android:versionName/ s/="[^"][^"]*"/="NEW VERSION NAME"/' AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: Note that this depends on the line-breaks as entered in the question, with one attribute per line.  If the XML gets reformatted and the non-significant whitespace is collapsed, then you'll need the attribute name to be part of the match and replacement: `s/\(android:versionName\)="[^"]*"/\1="NEW VERSION NAME"/` (I've also changed to permit empty string - again, just in case.

Comment: @TobySpeight Well, there's always [this warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg).  But assuming the OP has a tight control over how the XML is generated, it can still be done the easy way.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the nature of xml and the version number, it is actually very safe to use a simpler command:

```
sed -i '/versionName/s/".*"/"NEW VERSION NAME"/' AndroidManifest.xml
```

P.S. in my opinion, it is very important to be able to simplify your shell script based on specific circumstances and reasonable assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\([[:blank:]]android:versionName="\)[^"]*"/\1Your New Value"/' YourFile
```

- assuming that all section that have `android:versionName` will be changed
- with GNU sed still better with replacing `[[:blan:k]]` by `\(^\|[[:blank:]]\)` (and a `-i` if direct modification avoiding temporary file)